# Wordpress PeepSo modification - display WP comments in activity stream

Tags: wordpress, plugins, wordpress-plugin-creation

I am working on a website that will have social media features and I am using the PeepSo plugin for most of the features. Unfortunately, this plugin does not allow the admin to approve posts and comments before they are posted, and this is the functionality that is the most important to me. I found a way to approve the posts - I integrated the User Submitted Posts plugin with PeepSo, but I want the comments to be approved too.

When a user submits a post it is displayed in the PeepSo activity stream, and then they can click on it and it will be displayed as a WP post. Then they can comment on it using WP comments, these comments can be moderated before they are posted.

But the users can also comment directly from the activity stream and these comments are handled by PeepSo and are posted directly without admin approval.

So I want to try some of these workarounds:

1. Delete the PeepSo comment function, which will only enable the user to comment after clicking on a post, then the comments will be handled by WP
2. Find a way to code the WP comments to be displayed in the PeepSo activity stream, so that the user can comment directly from the stream and the comments can be approved by the admin before they are posted
3. Find a way to make the PeepSo comments from the stream to be approved by the admin before they are posted, so that there will be no need for the WP comments.

I can delete the PeepSo comment function, but I don't like this idea, because it makes user interactions a bit harder with more clicks required. I would like to be able to make option 2 or 3 possible, but I am worried about messing with the PeepSo plugin code. Maybe you can help me with how to do it and not crash my website?

PeepSo has an option to integrate PeepSo comments with WP comments, but it only works one way - gets rid of the WP comments, and only allows PeepSo comments on the entire website.

Please help me, I would really appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

Please notice that PeepSo used its own comments with his own Tables.
They don't integrade the comments from Wordpress but they deactivate them.

I have a simular problem with Borlabs Caching tool, While PeepSo used its own comments, Borlabs Cache can't update the post automaticly after new comments.